# Counting and output the numbers in a dynamic interval as a table (R)

Tags: r, dataframe, math

Very new to R, trying to make a table as so:

```
"range","number"
"0.000->0.510",863
"0.510->1.020",21
"1.020->1.530",2
"1.530->2.040",2
"2.040->2.550",0
"2.550->3.059",2
"3.059->3.596",0
"3.596->4.079",3
"4.079->4.589",1
"4.589->5.099",1
```

which is a csv file output. My mission was to identify each line of an .data file (which can be seen as a one-column data frame where looks like this but much longer.

```
0.5172000000000001
3.796199999999999
0.6227940000000004
1.3956000000000004
5.098802999999999
0.6755999999999986
1.6382092558672117
```

I've used a line like this `rangeInterval <- seq(0, maxTime, maxTime/10)` to get a new vector(where maxTime here is 5.098803), but I have no idea how should I convert to the table presents at front. Am I suppose to make a loop and try to build a vector with each element is rangeInterval's [index]->[index+1] or what? Also how am I suppose to make it 3 decimals long?

---

edit: The solution after I figured it

```
rangeInterval <- seq(0,maxTime-maxTime/10, maxTime/10)
range1 <- subset(ssdata,0<V1 & V1<(maxTime/10))
range2 <- subset(ssdata,V1>(maxTime/10)*1 & V1<=(maxTime/10)*2)
range3 <- subset(ssdata,V1>(maxTime/10)*2 & V1<=(maxTime/10)*3)
range4 <- subset(ssdata,V1>(maxTime/10)*3 & V1<=(maxTime/10)*4)
range5 <- subset(ssdata,V1>(maxTime/10)*4 & V1<=(maxTime/10)*5)
range6 <- subset(ssdata,V1>(maxTime/10)*5 & V1<=(maxTime/10)*6)
range7 <- subset(ssdata,V1>(maxTime/10)*6 & V1<=(maxTime/10)*7)
range8 <- subset(ssdata,V1>(maxTime/10)*7 & V1<=(maxTime/10)*8)
range9 <- subset(ssdata,V1>(maxTime/10)*8 & V1<=(maxTime/10)*9)
range10 <- subset(ssdata,V1>(maxTime/10)*9& V1<=(maxTime/10)*10)
#I'm sure there's an easier to do this...
rangeList <- c(range1, range2, range3, range4, range5, range6, range7, range8, range9, range10)

#The part to make the range column
newc = lapply(rangeInterval, doNothing)
newc2 = lapply(newc, plusInterval)
newc = lapply(newc, threeDecimal)
newc2 = lapply(newc2, threeDecimal)

#The part to make the dataframe basic
df <- data.frame(range = rangeInterval)
df$range <- paste0(newc,"->",newc2)
```

Where rangeInterval was the one-column dataframe I present before.

Comment: Are you looking for `cut` or `findInterval` perhaps? Your question isn't very clear.

Comment: It sounds like you're after `table(cut(x, seq(0, max(x), max(x)/10)))` (where "x" is a vector with the values you've shared starting with 0.5172...)

Comment: I've searched for `cut`, it seems not really giving me the result I need...Tried `table(cut(0.5172, seq(0, max(x), max(x)/10)))` Cut seems to be able to identify my 0.5172 is in the range between 0.51 and 1.02, which is my second interval, which is good. But what I need is to check for all the lines in a data file(where each line of it is a number between some dynamic interval, which can be made by `maxTime/10`) and output both the range and the amount of number in this range to build a new table as what I showed at very beginning. Sorry if I didn't present my question very clear.

Comment: Say in the data file the script found 863 numbers that belong to the interval between 0.000->0.510

Comment: The thing I used at last was subset. Also I used paste0 to add both variables and the arrow indicator.